# I want to change the storybook version 6 file to version 7 file

Tags: reactjs, next.js

The code below is the setting file of the storybook version 6. I installed the latest version of the storybook, and it was installed in version 7.
The setting file for version 6 is main.js, so I have to change it to main.ts.

```
    import { addDecorator } from '@storybook/react'
    import { createGlobalStyle, ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components'
    import { theme } from '../src/themes'
    import * as NextImage from 'next/image'


    export const parameters = {
      actions: { argTypesRegex: '^on[A-Z].*' },
      controls: {
        matchers: {
          color: /(background|color)$/i,
          date: /Date$/,
        },
      },
    }

    export const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
      html,
      body,
      textarea {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Oxygen,
          Ubuntu, Cantarell, Fira Sans, Droid Sans, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
      }
      * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      a {
        text-decoration: none;
        transition: .25s;
        color: #000000;
      }
`


    addDecorator((story) => (
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <GlobalStyle />
        {story()}
      </ThemeProvider>
    ))


    const OriginalNextImage = NextImage.default;

    Object.defineProperty(NextImage, 'default', {
      configurable: true,
      value: (props) => typeof props.src === 'string' ? (
        <OriginalNextImage {...props} unoptimized blurDataURL={props.src} />
      ) : (
        <OriginalNextImage {...props} unoptimized />
      ),
    })
```

Below is the code for version 7

```
    import type { Preview } from "@storybook/react";

    const preview: Preview = {
      parameters: {
        actions: { argTypesRegex: "^on[A-Z].*" },
        controls: {
          matchers: {
            color: /(background|color)$/i,
            date: /Date$/,
          },
        },
      },
    };

    export default preview;
```

I don't know how to fix it because the code structure is different.
Please help me.